# Functions for converting escaped unicode string to readable string C++

Tags: c++, unicode

this question has been asked before, many people have adviced to write the function by yourself. Still I would like to ask:

Is there a function/library to convert strings containing stuff like `"\\u003e"` and other unicode codes to readable `">"`? In Java I heard about "unescape()" but is there something in C++?

Since there are a lot of unicode symbols that can appear in a long textfile, it would be very helpful and save everybody a little time to have a standard function to convert **all** possible unicode symbols.

thanks

Comment: What is the input and output format exactly?  C++ has 2-3 different character formats (8,16,32), and infinite numbers of encodings.  7 bit clean US-ascii to utf-32?

Comment: Sorry I'm not that experienced in character formats: I get the string as json from the web and would like to output it to a string on the runtime, I guess its something standard?

Comment: It depends on the operating system. The question has been asked many times before but people don't bother to give any detail. `\u003E` is standard ASCII character, `char c = (char)0x3E;` no conversion is needed.

Comment: Hi I'm on Mac, I was reading about doing it with hex values, still getting "\u003e" from "\\u003e" means iterating through the string, looking which 4 chars are fullowed by the "\\u" and then add an if-case for every possible unicode symbol? My problem is actually how to construct "\u003e" from the string "u003e"..

Comment: "*I get the string as json from the web*" - the encoding you are taling about is part of the JSON spec, so you should be using a JSON parser (there are plenty available) that handles encoding/decoding for you so you can focus on the plain Unicode strings.

Comment: "*`"\\u003e"` means iterating through the string, looking which 4 chars are fullowed by the `"\\u"` and then add an if-case for every possible unicode symbol?*" - you would extract the 4 chars, parse them as a hex-encoded 16-bit unsigned integer (you can use `istream::operator>>` with `std::hex`, or `std::stoi()`, for that parsing), cast it to `wchar_t` or `char16_t` (depending on whether you are using `std::wstring` or `std::u16string`), and then finally replace the original 6-char sequence with the new single char. But any decent JSON parser will handle this kind of logic for you.